# pause a runnable thread and wait for user input

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have to copy a bunch of files from one location to another. This I will do in an AsyncTask so I can easily display a progressBar while the operation is happening.

But lets say one fo the files being copied already exists in the new location, can then pause the asynctask and display an alert dialog saying skip or overwrite?

From what I have understood its not possible inside the asynctask. But is there a smart way to achieve something similar? Or should I go through the list, that might be 1000+ files, before and check if they exist in the new location?

What would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you can do something like this:

```
public ? doInBackground(?... ?s) {
    while (shouldCopy) {
        while (needUserVerfication)
            if (!verifying) 
                publishProgress(NEED_USER_VERIFICATION);
        else
            // ...
    }
}

public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... ints) {
    switch (ints[0]) {
    case NEED_USER_VERIFICATION:
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        adb.setTitle("Lisen!");
        adb.setMessage("I need your input");
        adb.setPostiveClickListener("Accept", this)
        adb.setNegativeClickListener("Cancel", this)
        adb.show();
    case PUBLISH_PROGRESS:
        // Update progress
    }
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (DialogInterface.POSITIVE == which) {
        needUserVerification = true
    } else {
        needUserVerification = false
    }
    verifying = false
}
```

Because `publishProgress` makes `onProgressUpdate` run in the main thread, all should be dandy.